# Single "=" after dependency version specifier in setup.py

Tags: python, conda, versioning, setup.py

I'm looking at a `setup.py` with this syntax:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
...
    tests_require=["h5py>=2.9=mpi*",
                   "mpi4py"]
)
```

I understand the idea of the ">=" where `h5py` should be at least version 2.9, but I cannot for the life of me understand the `=mpi*` afterwards. Is it saying the version should somehow match the mpi version, while also being at least 2.9?

I can't find anything that explains specifying python package versions that also explains the use of a single `=`.

The only other place I've found it used is some obscure blog post that seemed to imply it was sort of like importing the package with an alias, which doesn't make much sense to me; and also the [mpi4py docs](https://mpi4py-fft.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) that include a command line snippet `conda install -c conda-forge h5py=*=mpi* netcdf4=*=mpi*` but don't really explain it.

Comment: For conda specification, [see here near the bottom](https://conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/package-spec.html#id6) - it's a "build string", implying that "mpi" should be present in such. Doesn't that package use [this setuptools plugin](https://github.com/chrisjbillington/setuptools-conda)? If yes, then this format is just conda-specific (and the plugin does the magic to manage installs properly). Could you share project repo, if it is in public domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Short answer

The `=mpi*` qualifier says that you want to install `h5py` pre-compiled with MPI support.

##### Details

If you look at the documentation for h5py, you'll see references to having to build it with or without MPI explicitly (e.g., see https://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/build.html).

When you look at the conda-forge download files (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/h5py/files) you'll also see that there are a bunch of `nompi` variants and a bunch of `mpi` variants.

Adding `=mpi*` triggers getting a version that's been compiled with MPI so that you get parallel MPI support, while I suspect the default version would come without MPI support.

##### Experimentation with and without

When I do `conda install -c conda-forge h5py=3.7`, conda proposes to download this bundle:

```
h5py-3.7.0-nompi_py39hd4deaf1_100
```

But when I did `conda install =c conda-forget h5py=3.7=mpi*`, I expected a `...-mpi_py...` bundle but instead it just failed because I'm on Windows and MPI is not supported on Windows as far as I can tell. (And that makes sense, HPC clusters with MPI run on Linux.)